# After updating to Angular 13, no main-es2015 / main-es5 files created

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After updating to Angular 13, with same script, I got only single main.js file for production build.

Is there is some changes to build process?
Options at build:

```
--statsJson=true --configuration=prod
```